# Printing the value of the configuration

Tags: kframework

While modifying the toy language SIMPLE from the tutorial, I thought it would be helpful to have a statement that would just print the current configuration so that I could see the internal state of the program as it ran. To that end I added to `Stmt`a `printConfig` command. In the semantics then I figured all I had to do was rewrite this to a call to `print` taking the body of the `T` cell so I added

```
rule <k> printConfig; => print(cfg); </k>
     <T> cfg </T>
```

The kompiler throws an error saying that there is an unexpected end parenthesis, specifically the one for `print(cfg)`. I'd encountered a similar issue previously and in that case the error turned out to be due to the typing of the components of the two statements I had. I'm wondering then if there is a way to "cast" the value in the `T` cell as an `Exp` so I can print it.

If there is a better way I can debug my semantics that does not involve this I am very open to that as well. Thank you!

Comment: `krun` has a `--depth N` option that lets you stop rewriting after `N` steps have been taken, printing out the configuration at that point.

Comment: Note that the semantics of `print` in SIMPLE can only handle String and Int. Extending it to print configurations would involve writing code to convert configurations to strings.

Comment: Right, I was wondering if there is a way to convert configurations into strings but for now I'll settle with the depth option which seems much cleaner anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well one issue I can see is that you have `<k>` and `<T>` cells next to each other in your rule, but they don't have a sibling relationship in the initial configuration.

The SIMPLE configuration looks like this, where the `<k>` cell is a grandchild of the `<T>` cell:

```
  configuration <T color="red">
                  <threads color="orange">
                    <thread multiplicity="*" color="yellow">
                      <k color="green"> $PGM:Stmts ~> execute </k>
                      <control color="cyan">
                        <fstack color="blue"> .List </fstack>
                        <xstack color="purple"> .List </xstack>
                      </control>
                      <env color="violet"> .Map </env>
                      <holds color="black"> .Map </holds>
                      <id color="pink"> 0 </id>
                    </thread>
                  </threads>
                  <genv color="pink"> .Map </genv>
                  <store color="white"> .Map </store>
                  <busy color="cyan"> .Set </busy>
                  <terminated color="red"> .Set </terminated>
                  <input color="magenta" stream="stdin"> .List </input>
                  <output color="brown" stream="stdout"> .List </output>
                  <nextLoc color="gray"> 0 </nextLoc>
                </T>
```

So if you want to write your rule, you at least have to do this:

```
syntax Stmt ::= "printConfig" ";"
rule <T> ... <k> printConfig; => print(CFG); ... </k> ... </T> #as CFG
```

Notice that I made three changes here, (1) I used capital letters for the variable CFG (which is conventional in K), (2) I added the `...` to the end of the `<k>` cell, which allows you to use `printConfig;` anywhere instead of just at the end of a program, and (3) I used an `_#as_` pattern to match both the super-term `<T> ... </T>` as well as the sub-term `<k> ... </k>` at the same time, giving the name `CFG` to the super-term.

`_#as_` patterns are documented in the [Pending Documentation](https://github.com/kframework/k/blob/master/pending-documentation.md#as-patterns).

Hope that helps!